# ExtJS change mask target while opening an Ext.Window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS application and I want to change the mask target while showing an `Ext.Window`. Now when I show the window, the entire DOM is masked, but I want to mask just a DIV. Overriding `getMaskTarget` is not working, it gets the target through an `Ext.panel.Header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can setup you window as `modal: false` and mask any component / element in window `show` event handler (remove mask in `hide` or `destroy` event handler depending on your `closeAction`)?